# Printing Checks with Latex

Tags: margins, paper-size

This is my first time working with Latex and I'm using Texmaker to create it in. I was hoping to find some GUI Editing tool that kind of let me drag and drop things where I wanted them but couldn't find one :) ha ha

I am trying to make a simple layout for printing on my checks from my bank. I have the following so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,landscape]{letter}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}
\hoffset = 0pt
\voffset = 0pt
\oddsidemargin = 0pt
\topmargin = 0pt
\headheight = 0pt
\headsep = 0pt
\marginparsep = 0pt
\marginparwidth = 0pt
\footskip = 0pt
\usepackage[pass,paperwidth=2.5in,paperheight=6.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ p{4.15in} l }
Guatemala 05 de Septiembre del 2,012 & 125.00 \\ 
\multicolumn{2}{ l }{Name of Person} \\
\multicolumn{2}{ l }{Ciento Venticinco con 00/100} \\
\end{tabular} 

\end{document}
```

Now this prints yes, but two problems. First off I am testing with regular sheets of paper till I get it down pat, and right now it goes down to the halfway point in the sheet of paper and then prints. Plus it's not landscape, it's normal printing.

What do I have to change here? I want it to be exact check size and I want to be able to put my checks in the printer vertically in the middle of the printer and have them print.

Any clues?

Comment: You shouldn't `pass` the geometry settings: actually, it's precisely what I believe would get you what you want. Perhaps with `\usepackage[paperwidth=6.5in,paperheight=2.5in]{geometry}` (I switched width and height) instead of the `landscape` class option?

Comment: Doing that it prints and though the PDF output looks good it now prints upside down and still not vertically :( And prints at what would be the bottom of the page, so it's pulling the whole page down then prints upside down horizontally on the page's bottom.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it! The problem wasn't latex but the printing wasn't set to landscape and the correct paper size. So I just used CLI to print: `lp -o media=2.5x6.5 -o landscape check.pdf`

Comment: @henrique If you want go ahead and post your answer as an answer and I will accept it :) Worked like a charm, thanks.

Comment: As the problem wasn't LaTeX and the solution via the CLI, I closed the question.

Comment: Actually please read above, the problem was Latex since I has to change the paper sizes and remove the pass problem to begin with. Without that change the landscape wouldn't have worked.

Comment: @jfreak53: I'd be willing to cast a reopen vote (you have one already, need five) *if* you edit your question to fit the specific problem you had: "How do I produce document in a check-sized format and in landscape?". You could get rid of all the AMS packages as well as `inputenc`, since they're not relevant for the problem, and reduce the document body to a simple "Hello world". Feel free to `@`-let me know when you're done. As your question will then be at the top of the start page, other users with the reopening privilege will see this and react, hopefully.